# Regular expressions: Matching strings starting with dot (.)?

Tags: regex

I am a complete Reg-exp noob, so please bear with me. Tried to google this, but haven't found it yet.

What would be an appropriate way of writing a Regular expression matching files starting with a dot, such as `.buildpath` or `.htaccess`?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In most regex languages, `^\.` or `^[.]` will match a leading dot.

Comment: I don't think your second regex is working. At least in perl/java/php will not work as you intend.

Comment: @Toader: WTF?  It does work exactly as intended in in Perl, Java, PHP, grep, awk, and other tools I've tested just now.

Comment: damn .. i thought that [] means any one of the inner expression and . means any char. I guess is a special case. Need to read about that ;). Sorry you are right.

Answer (score 7):

The `^` matches the beginning of a string in most languages. This will match a leading `.`. You need to add your filename expression to it.

```
^\.
```

Likewise, `$` will match the end of a string.

Comment: Wouldn't `^\.` suffice? Or `^\..+`? Yours matches the examples, but odd event of `.1st_pwd` fails.

Comment: Yes, [a-z] would need to be replaced by his actual expression for filenames. It is simply an example.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to substitute the `\` for the respective language escape character. However, under Powershell the Regex I use is: `^(\.)+\/`

Test case:

```
"../NameOfFile.txt" -match '^(\\.)+\\\/'
```

works, while

```
"_./NameOfFile.txt" -match '^(\\.)+\\\/'
```

does not.

Naturally, you may ask, well what is happening here?

The (`\\.`) searches for the literal `.` followed by a `+`, which matches the previous character at least once or more times.

Finally, the `\\\/` ensures that it conforms to a Window file path.

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on the regular expression library you use, but you can do something like this:

```
^\.\w+
```

The `^` anchors the match to the beginning of the string, the `\.` matches a literal period (since an unescaped `.` in a regular expression typically matches any character), and `\w+` matches 1 or more "word" characters (alphanumeric plus `_`).

See the [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) documentation for more info on Perl-style regular expressions and their syntax.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what characters are legal in a filename, which depends on the OS and filesystem.

For example, in Windows that would be:

`^\.[^<>:"/\\\|\?\*\x00-\x1f]+$`

The above expression means:

- Match a string starting with the literal character `.`
- Followed by *at least one* character which is not one of (whole class of invalid chars follows)

I used [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as reference regarding which chars are disallowed in filenames.

Answer (score 1):

To match the string starting with dot in java you will have to write a simple expression

```
^\\..*
```

^ means regular expression is to be matched from start of string
\. means it will start with string literal "."
.* means dot will be followed by 0 or more characters

Answer (score 0):

If you are using javascript, regex might not be needed in this case. You could just use the [startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) method:

```
if ('.buildpath'.startsWith('.')) {
  console.log('String starts with a dot');
}
```