# Regular expressions (regex) for string starting with three dots

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an array of strings in java script and I need to find those that start with three dots.
Then I need to delete these dots and everything after "?".

Example:

```
"...how to do this? - Th0be [22.2.2022]" -> "how to do this?"
```

For the first part I tried the `^\.` regex (reference to [Regular expressions: Matching strings starting with dot (.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640879/regular-expressions-matching-strings-starting-with-dot)), but this should be only for one dot and it did not work anyway.

For the second part, I figured out the `[^?]*$` regex. It looks correct, but I put it here just to be sure.

I am beginner with regex.
Any idea, how to do mainly first part?

Comment: What should be the match in `....how. To do this?`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `^\.{3}` to match 3 dots.

```js
let s = "...how to do this? - Th0be [22.2.2022]";
console.log(s.replace(/^\.{3}([^?]*\?).*/, "$1"));
```